# Can HTML5 or a JS library precache video?

Tags: html

I would like to play video on over 100 devices at the same time. We should have enough internet bandwidth for this, but Murphy's law says I should plan for such a risk.

If this can be precached on devices before the video must be played, it gives much more time to for the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how big is the video, you could fetch it entirely on the device's memory as a Blob. Then you'd just have to play this downloaded Blob :

```js
fetch('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4')
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    console.log('got it all, ready to play');
    vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    vid.controls = true;
    vid.onended = e => URL.revokeObjectURL(vid.src);
  });
```

```html
<video id="vid"></video>
```

(XHR also has a `responseType = 'blob'` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

```
<video preload ...>
```

> The preload attribute informs the browser whether or not the video
>   data should begin downloading as soon as the video tag is loaded. The
>   options are auto, metadata, and none.
>
> 'auto': Start loading the video immediately (if the browser agrees).
>   Some mobile devices like iPhones and iPads will not preload the video
>   in order to protect their users' bandwidth. This is why the value is
>   called 'auto' and not something more final like 'true'.
>
> 'metadata': Load only the meta data of the video, which includes
>   information like the duration and dimensions of the video.
>
> 'none': Don't preload any of the video data. This will wait until the
>   user clicks play to begin downloading.

From http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/options.html